# Knowledge on weighted integral operators?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-kernel

There are tons of books and a huge literature on the properties of the following integral operator:
\begin{equation}
T(f) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} K(x,\cdot)f(x)dx,
\end{equation}
where $K(x,z)$ is, say, a Mercer kernel.

I am wondering if people have systematically studied the properties (spectrum for example) of the following weighted integral operator:
\begin{equation}
T^*(f) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} K(x,\cdot)f(x)d\mu(x),
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is a non-Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{X}$. And I am imagining that if $\mu$ is closer to the Lebesgue measure, $T$ and $T^*$ should be more similar to each other. Are you all aware of anything on this topic? Thanks!